# How do I save the current cursor position and load it later in Vimscript?

Tags: vim

I've written a function for removing the excess white space in a file:

```
let g:trim_whitespace = 1

function! TrimWhitespace()
    if g:trim_whitespace
        normal :%s/\s\+$//e
    endif
endfunction
```

The issue is that the cursor position is set to `[1, 1]` after the substitution command. I don't want the cursor to move at all, so I tried to save the cursor position and reset it after the substitute command:

```
let a:cursor_pos = getpos(".")
normal :%s/\s\+$//e
exec cursor(a:cursor_pos[1], a:cursor_pos[2])
```

But still the exact same thing happens, as if the call to `cursor` had no effect. Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. `:execute` is for evaluation of *Ex commands*, but `cursor()` is a built-in *function*. You need to invoke it with `:call cursor(a:cursor_pos[1], a:cursor_pos[2])`. Also, you don't need `:normal` in your function to execute the `:substitute` command; just write `%s/\s\+$//e`.
2. There's a corresponding `setpos()` function which is simpler to invoke: `:call setpos('.', a:cursor_pos)`
3. The jumps in the buffer may still change the *view*, i.e. what part of the buffer is visible. To avoid that, you need to use `winsaveview()` / `winrestview()` (which include the cursor position).
4. Your function still clobbers the search history, and has other shortcomings like failing on no-modifiable buffers. Especially for this particular, very common functionality, there exist several solutions, for example my [DeleteTrailingWhitespace plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3967). (The plugin page has links to alternative plugins.) Don't (poorly) reinvent the wheel when you don't have to!

Comment: Isn't reinventing the wheel good for learning? :) Thanks for a great explanation.

Comment: It's fine then (but you could / should? have mentioned that you're aware of those other solutions). Note how I didn't just post a plugin recommendation, but explicitly addressed your code to help you learn. Have fun!

Answer (score 8):

Try placing a mark:

```
mark `
%s/\s\+$//e
normal ``
```

Comment: Thanks, @romainl. I am using this for a macro to re-indent a paragraph - `let @p='mt{jgq}`t'` - where `t` is my temporary register.

Answer (score 0):

Combine substitute with setline

```
function! SubstiTute()
    let l = 1
    for line in getline(1, '$')
        call setline(l, substitute(line, "\\v +$", "", "g"))
        let l = l + 1
    endfor
endfun
"call SubstiTute()
```